How to get access to agents parameters from inside the dynamic event in anylogic?
I am trying to get access to the agent parameters from inside the dynamic event 
But the following method in the picture, is not working. When the agents enter the Unload-Wait block, I am creating the create_Calc(1,SECOND,agent). And the idea is to keep repeating until the agent parameter Unloader is equals to agent parameter MaxWeight.

You have set the type of your argument cont to the general Agent type, which does not have the attributes you are using. Set it to the type you are creating in the source mother_Vessel

